# How do I simplify $\Gamma\left(\frac{2021}{2}\right)$?

Tags: gamma-function, beta-function

I was tasked to evaluate the Beta function $$B\left(\frac{2021}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right) \tag{1}$$

I've expanded this to
$$\frac{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{2021}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(1011)} \tag{2}$$

How do I simplify $\Gamma\left(\dfrac{2021}{2}\right)$ and then $(2)$, knowing that $\Gamma(1011) = 1010!$ and $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \sqrt \pi$ ?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3087088/how-to-find-gamman3-2), with $n=2019$.

Answer (score 1):

Check the duplication formula here https://brilliant.org/wiki/gamma-function/#eulers-reflection-formula , with $z=2020/2$, so that:

$\Gamma(2020/2+1/2)\Gamma(1010)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2019}}\Gamma(2020)$ [1]

Note that from here one can get:
$\Gamma(2020/2+1/2)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2019}}\frac{2019!}{1009!}$.

Therefore, using your expansion and the above:

$B(2021/2,1/2)=\frac{\pi}{2^{2019}}\frac{2019!}{1010!1009!}=\frac{\pi}{2^{2019}}\binom{2019}{1010}$

Is the last form acceptable ? Using the same methodology one could check the general identity:

$$B\left(k+\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2^{2k-1}}\binom{2k-1}{k}$$

for every $k$ natural. For $k=1010$ we have the OP expression.

Comment: Yes. That would answer my question. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome :) If the question is answered, could you accept it?

Comment: Not sure as I do not have the answer (Teacher simply saidyou will get a nice looking answer), but this answer looks nice enough in my opinion.

Comment: Sure I am curious :)

Answer (score 1):

[Legendre's duplication formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDuplicationFormula.html):
$$\Gamma(2z)=\frac{2^{2z-1}\Gamma(z)\Gamma(z+1/2)}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$
Using $z=2021/2$,
$$\Gamma(2021)=\frac{2^{2\frac{2021}{2}-1}\Gamma(2021/2)\Gamma(2021/2+1/2)}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$
$$2020!=\frac{2^{2020}\Gamma(2021/2)\cdot1010!}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$
$$\Gamma(2021/2)=\sqrt{\pi}\frac{2020!}{2^{2020}1010!}$$